# Is it a good idea to expose Vulkan's function pointers globally?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I just loaded a shared library for the first time at runtime. What I am currently doing is that I create an explicit context where all function pointers are loaded.

It would roughly look like this in C++

```
auto entry = load_vk(..);
auto instance = entry.CreateInstance(...);
VkInstancePointer vk = load_vk_static_fn(instance);
vk.CreateDevice(...);
```

The problem is that I am not sure about the lifetime of this. I would need to access `vk` across different threads, so I am currently wrapping it in a `shared_ptr<VkInstancePointer>`. I also unload the library in the destructor.

The sort of problem that I am having is that I want to make the vulkan api a bit more convenient so that I am able to write

```
physical_device.create_logical_device(...);
```

But that would mean that a `physical_device` needs to contain a `shared_ptr<VkInstancePointer>`. That means that a lot of stuff will have an additional overhead of an atomic counter increment.

I am wondering if I could just load the vulkan function pointers globally?

```
load_entry();
auto instance = CreateInstance();
load_instance_fp(instance);
auto device = CreateDevice(..);
```

I usually never use globals but it seems that it would make sense here.

Do I ever want to unload the Vulkan library at some point?

Comment: Generally speaking, a shared object / DLL loaded dynamically at runtime the _correct_ way increments a reference counter. Freeing it decrements that reference counter and the library cannot be removed from your process until 0 references remain. You're better off loading the library every time you need to acquire a function pointer to keep reference counting consistent, or simply never unload it.

Comment: "*That means that a lot of stuff will have an additional overhead of an atomic counter increment.*" Only the copy operations involved with those objects.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes and the creation of those objects. But as Andon M. Coleman said I lose the ability to unload the library. I could store a weak_ptr but then accessing it would always increment the atomic counter. I probably just make the `VkInstancePointer` globally accessible.

Comment: @MaikKlein: "*But as Andon M. Coleman said I lose the ability to unload the library.*" ... why do you need to? The library will be unloaded when your application terminates. Why would you need to unload Vulkan before then?

Comment: @NicolBolas That is what I asked above, I wasn't sure if would need to do that at one point. Like for example switching to different versions of Vulkan at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of function pointers in Vulkan: instance function pointers and device function pointers.

Instance function pointers are retrieved via `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`. This function can retrieve function pointers for functions that are device-independent. That is, for functions that deal with creating/managing/destroying devices, as opposed to functions that talk directly to a device (ie: any function that takes a `VkDevice`, `VkQueue` or `VkCommandBuffer`).

But it also can retrieve pointers for functions that talk to the device itself . These functions can talk to *any* Vulkan device, whether it was created before or after the function pointers were retrieved.

By contrast, `vkGetDeviceProcAddr` gets *device* function pointers. These function pointers are specific to a device; they *cannot* be used with a different device from the one they were created with.

So you can create global function pointers which can be used from any thread to talk to any device. But they have to be instance function pointers.

Or you can just let the Vulkan SDK do its job and handle all of this for you.

> Do I ever want to unload the Vulkan library at some point?

I don't know of a reason why you would want to. Users generally can't install new versions of a driver-level system like Vulkan without a restart of the machine. And even if you could, your code wouldn't know what to do with its new stuff, since your code was written against a lower version.

Comment: Could you point me to the Vulkan SDK that is supposed to handle that for me? Is it this one https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers ? Specifically this function https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/common/vulkan_wrapper.cpp#L24 ?